# Access saved wifi connections and their passwords on android sdk >=30

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to retrieve all wifis that are saved on a device (were used before) and if it is possible get their passwords.

I tried couple of libraries to do it but none of them managed to do what I'd like to achieve.
The closest to the solution was wifi_iot flutter library.
I managed to get all wifis that are currently available and there is method to check whether connection was registered before or not, but in newer version of android sdk >= 29 it doesn't work (and password field is always null).

Is it even possible to get these data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the password of a WiFi network unless your app is a [Privileged app](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist) (i.e. an app that is pre-loaded on the device).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know anything about retrieving previously used WIFIs?

Comment: I don't, sorry!